# Jquery appropriation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I encountered with snippet of code in the jQuery menu library. I'm new to jQuery so can somebody explain what `$(this)` in `cssmenu` variable means (its a kind of context?).

```js
$.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
   var cssmenu = $(this), 
   settings = $.extend({
      title:  "Menu",
      format: "dropdown",
      sticky: false
   }, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code defines a jQuery plugin, by adding a function to the jQuery's object prototype. In the context of a plugin's initializer function, `$(this)` is totally unecessary: `this` in the context of a plugin function already refers to a jQuery object.

Not only that, but the way the plugin is written doesn't follow jQuery principles where a plugin might be called on a jQuery object wrapping over multiple DOM elements.

The plugin's definition also doesn't take in account the fact that `jQuery.noConflict()` would be used.

A form that would make more sense is:

```
//Using an IIFE and passing jQuery allow us to use $ safely
(function($) {

    $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {

        //Apply defaults
        options = $.extend({
            title: "Menu",
            format: "dropdown",
            sticky: false
        }, options);

        //Initialize the plugin for every DOM element in the jQuery oject
        //and return the jQuery object to avoid breaking chaining
        return this.each(function() {
            //In here, this points to a DOM element, that's why we wrap it
            //in a DOM object
            initPlugin($(this), options);
        });

    };

    function initPlugin($el, options) {
        //The plugin would be applied here to $el
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hmm if i will delete this some part of menu will disappear
http://jsfiddle.net/th61eg8m/1/

Comment: @МикитаЧумак Once you enter `this.each`, the initialization process should be seen as seperated processes for every elements. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to share your `cssmenu`. Think about it like if you were instanciating a new object for every `this.each` iteration, which applies logic to the current iterated DOM element. Is that clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the whole thing step by step:

```
$.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
}
```

This defines a jQuery plugin called `menumaker`, taking an options object. It is run as `$('mySelector').menumaker({})`.

```
  var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({}, options);
```

Now, `this` is going to be the jQuery object `$('mySelector')` from the above example. Wrapping it in another jQuery constructor (`$(this)`) is rather redundant.

But in any case, it's saved as a variable named `cssmenu`. A `settings` variable is also created, applying the passed in objects to the default settings.

---

So basically, yes, it's the context. It's also pointless.

Answer (score -2):

Basically $.fn.menumaker means its allows you to extend jquery with your own function, which in turn will be available to all jquery objects.

So the this, is the Jquery equivalent of the DOM object with which you have used plugin function.

Comment: `this` is already a jQuery object in that context, not a DOM element.

Comment: Thanks double-checked on that now.